# handling selects in odataqueryoptions in core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, odata

I've got a regular controller, that has odata capabilities:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ChannelsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ChannelContext db = new ChannelContext();
    public IQueryable<PrdChannel> Get()
    {
        var entities = db.PrdChannel.AsQueryable();
        var modelManager = (IODataModelManger) HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IODataModelManger));
        var model = modelManager.GetModel(nameof(ProductConfiguration));
        var queryContext = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(PrdChannel), null);
        var queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, HttpContext.Request);

        return queryOptions
            .ApplyTo(entities, new ODataQuerySettings
            {
                HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.True
            })
            .Cast<PrdChannel>();
    }
}
```

I am able to issue a GET: `https://myservice/Channel?$filter=cable lt 10`

However, when I try to do a `$select`, it does not work!

`https://myservice/Channel?$select=cable`

Per the definition of `OdataQueryOptions`, it does not support select/expand.

**Question**: How do we support `$select` in aspnetcore?

Perhaps this should be an ODataController?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't apply $select when using ODataQueryOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636167/cant-apply-select-when-using-odataqueryoptions)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated: [Can't apply $select when using ODataQueryOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636167/cant-apply-select-when-using-odataqueryoptions/58824201#58824201)

To allow support for $select in OData, you cant Cast your IQueryable to a defined type, you need to use `dynamic` type instead.

```cs
    public IQueryable<dynamic> Get()
    {
        ... your code ...
        return queryOptions
            .ApplyTo(entities, new ODataQuerySettings
            {
                HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.True
            })
            as IQueryable<dynamic>;
    }
```