# Can't apply $select when using ODataQueryOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I am trying to implement querying to Sql Server via EF Core and OData(7.1.0).

Action method looks like follows:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<UserInfoDto> Get(ODataQueryOptions ops)
{
     return this.service.GetUserInfos(ops);
}
```

Service code:

```cs
public List<UserInfoDto> GetUserInfos(ODataQueryOptions ops)
{
    using (var context = new EFContext())
    {
        var query = context.Users.Join(context.Customers, x => x.CustomerId, y => y.Id, (x, y) => new UserInfoDto
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Age = x.Age,
            CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
            CustomerTitle = y.Title,
            CustomerDescription = y.Description
        });

        var result = ops.ApplyTo(query).Cast<UserInfoDto>().ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Startup `Configute` method:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     app.UseMvc(b => 
     {
         b.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Select().MaxTop(null);
         b.EnableDependencyInjection();
     });
}
```

However, when I am having `$select` in query (e.g https://localhost:5001/api/userinfos?$select=id), instead of projected result I am getting an error:

> InvalidOperationException: No coercion operator is defined between types
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder+SelectSome`1[Oda
>   taApp.UserInfoDto]' and 'OdataApp.UserInfoDto'.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you using `$select` query option for OData, you need an IQueryable of `dynamic` .

For example, imagine the following class:

```cs
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, if you have a query without `$select`, the IQueryable will generate a collection of Person, with all properties (id and name) in each item.

But, if you use a `$select=id` query, each item will have only the ID property and you cant Cast a dynamic type to a Person type.

In other words, you cant use `$select` and return a `List<UserInfoDto>`, you need to return a `List<dynamic>` without the Cast method, just like this:

```cs
    var result = ops.ApplyTo(query) as IQueryable<dynamic>;
    return result.ToList();
```

EDIT:

the full implementation of method will be:

```cs
// changing the return type
public List<dynamic> GetUserInfos(ODataQueryOptions<UserInfoDto> ops)
{
    using (var context = new EFContext())
    {
        var query = context.Users.Include(Customers, x => x.CustomerId, y => y.Id, (x, y) => new UserInfoDto
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Age = x.Age,
            CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
            CustomerTitle = y.Title,
            CustomerDescription = y.Description
        });
        // casting the applyto result
        var result = ops.ApplyTo(query) as IQueryable<dynamic>;
        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and let you know whether it works for me c:

Comment: Yeah, after your explanation things become quite logical to me!
Since OData `$select` does not cover a couple of complex queries I need, I guess I will stay with static DTO and forbid `$select` operations at all.

Anyway, many thanks for your help!

Comment: Object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[System.Object]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DtoExample]

Comment: @Jackie did you got way around this

Comment: @harishr I think @Jackie is trying to cast IQueryable<> back to IQueryable<DtoExample>, which is not working because the types of both are not able to cast each other. You dont need to cast the ApplyTo() back to your Dto or Model, because $select will change the type, like I said in my answer `you cant cast dynamic type to a Person type`. Please try to correct your code to not enforces a casting to a class of your solution.

Comment: @rodrigo the problem/error posted by Jackie is after removing the casting, $select still does not work

Comment: @harishr I didnt find solution for this exactly. But this is what I have decided to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16517768/5055668  This way you can apply $select on generic types

Comment: @Jackie I update the answer so you can see the full implementation of the method, I think your return type is not the same as the applyto casting one.

Comment: I dont have the model class definition, so I cant run myself an example. Using the .Select(string) will not work for $expand