# How to cast SelectExpandQueryOption to IQueryable<T> when using OData in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I have a WebAPI that is written in C# on the top of ASP.NET Core/5 framework.

I enabled [odata](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData) for my API. I am trying to manually apply the odata filter, order by clause, select columns and the expands.

Here is how I am trying to manually build the query using the `ODataQueryOptions`

```
protected IQueryable<TModel> BuildQuery(ODataQueryOptions<TModel> queryOptions, ODataQuerySettings settings)
{
    IQueryable<TModel> query = DbSet;

    if (queryOptions.SelectExpand != null)
    {
        var queryable = queryOptions.SelectExpand.ApplyTo(query, settings);

        query = queryable.Cast<TModel>(); // this causes an error
    }

    if (queryOptions.Filter != null)
    {
        query = queryOptions.Filter.ApplyTo(query, settings) as IQueryable<TModel>;  // this works!
    }

    if (queryOptions.OrderBy != null)
    {
        query = queryOptions.OrderBy.ApplyTo(query); // this works!
    }

    return query;
}
```

Everything above works great up until I try to expand a navigation property. When I do I get the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No coercion operator is defined between types 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Wrapper.SelectAllAndExpand`1[MyModel]' and 'MyModel'.'
```

Is there some sort of mapping that I need to do when defining the `IEdmModel` to build the navigation relations?

How can I correctly convert/cast `IQueryable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Wrapper.SelectAllAndExpand<TEntity>>` to `IQueryable<TEntity>`?

Here is the code behind [SelectAllAndExpand](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/f508cb983c98918dba440d5c4be4b304299834b0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/Query/Wrapper/SelectAllAndExpandOfT.cs)

Comment: probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636167/cant-apply-select-when-using-odataqueryoptions/ you cant convert a selectexpand query to a defined model, you need to cast it to dynamic, imagine a LINQ expression when `query` is a IEnumerable<TModel>, like `query.Select(t => new { t.Id, t.Name })` this query cannot be cast to IEnumerable<TModel>, because it generates an anonymous dynamic type, the selectexpand does the same, so you need to change your method to consider an IQueryable<dynamic> return.

Answer (score -1):

You can't directly cast

```
var queryable = queryOptions.SelectExpand.ApplyTo(query, settings);
```

to `IQueryable<TModel>`, because it different type of object.

If there is no Projection (`Select`) or Expand - you will get a regular object, but after Projection and Expand - it's a completely different thing.
Depending on your tasks, you should handle `SelectAllAndExpand<TModel>` or remove `SelectExpand.ApplyTo(..)`.